# monkey talk - how to judge there is one UI exists?

Tags: orientation, exists, monkeytalk

In `QTP`, we can use below code:

```
if obj1.exist(5)
   obj1.click;
else
   obj2.click
```

We can control the wait time and if one `UI` exists, we can do some operation.

how to work out the same situation in `Monkey Talk` with `JS`?

and can I get the orientation of the `IOS` device with `JS`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to see if a component exists, `Label * Verify %timeout=10000`. This will wait 10 seconds to find a label. You can use JavaScript like the following...

```
try {
    app.label().verify(); //if label exists
} catch(Exception err) {
    app.debug().print("Label not found");
}
```

To get the orientation you can do the following, `Device * var orientation`